# monotorrent c# не качает

Tags: c#, torrent

На VDS запустил раздачу torrent, пытаюсь начать скачивание через библиотеку Monotorrent (C# .Net). Код:

```
            EngineSettings settings = new EngineSettings {
                SavePath = //путь скачивания
                ListenPort = 19344
            };

            TorrentSettings torrentDefaults = new TorrentSettings();

            if (!Directory.Exists(settings.SavePath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(settings.SavePath);

            ClientEngine engine = new ClientEngine(settings);

            Torrent torrent = Torrent.Load(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\share.torrent");
            manager = new TorrentManager(torrent, engine.Settings.SavePath, torrentDefaults);

            engine.Register(manager);
            manager.StartAsync();
```

И, самое главное, сам торрент прекрасно скачивается через тотже uTorrent и прочие торрент клиенты. Торрент: https://yadi.sk/d/82S-3Jcf_1CTPQ

Comment: У вашего торрента нету трекеров по которому он мог бы найти с кого скачивать. В P2P сетях есть такие технологии, как DHT, которые ищут пиров без трекера, также есть те, которые ищут по локальной сети. Вы уверены, что MonoTorrent по умолчанию поддерживает это? На сколько я помню там надо было еще пару строк настроек вписать для их активации.

Comment: А какие именно настройки? Шарил по интернету, по DHT также смотрел, ничего толком не нашёл, а реализация этого скачивания очень сильно нужна.

Comment: Нашел такой [пример](https://github.com/alanmcgovern/monotorrent/blob/master/src/DhtSampleClient/Program.cs) у них, поищите получше, может найдете полный клиент. Я лично оооочень давно не работал с данной библиотекой, увы, подсказать больше нечего не могу.

Comment: В примере не понятно какая версия Monotorrent используется, в новой версии много сделано по-другому. Может Вы знаете какая версия используется там, или же какую-нибудь библиотеку посоветуете?

Comment: Как это не показано, там репозиторий с последними исходниками данной библиотеки, значит и версия последняя.

Comment: Я качал через NuGet и там многие функции поменяны.

Comment: Это что либо меняет? Я же вам сказал, что дал официальный репозиторий с последней версией библиотеки, они должны быть идентичны с NuGet.

Comment: Там написано, что файл изменялся on 10 Jun 2012

Comment: Где вы это увидели? Вот ссылка [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MonoTorrent) - `last updated 24 days ago` - `1.0.21`, сами исходники изменились [8 дней назад](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD66M.png). Если вы про тот кусок кода говорите, то он ссылается на директорию src, где лежит последняя версия, а значит эта часть кода не изменилась, либо автор дурак, который не захотел обновить пример. Вы вместо того, что бы спорить тут про версию, попробуйте реализовать сами, не уж то так трудно?

Comment: Пробовал, не получалось.

Comment: Во, нашел [полноценный](https://github.com/alanmcgovern/monotorrent/blob/master/src/SampleClient/main.cs) пример клиента со всем необходимым.

Comment: Дело в том, что если я возьму рандомный торрент с интернета (фильм / игра), то он будет прекрасно качаться. Но вот если я создаю торрент на другом компьютере, запускаю раздачу и пытаюсь со своего компьютера через своё приложение начать загрузку - происходит следующее: Мне приходит название, размер, и прочая информация о файле. Также я отследил и state торрента, выводит Downloading, что означает загрузка торрента, но скачивание не идёт, всё стоит по нулям (прогресс и количество скаченных байтов). Вы случайно не знаете, как создать торрент так, чтобы было аналогично как и с торрентом фильма?

Comment: Запустите ваш торрент в любой современном клиенте, зайдите в его свойства и найдите там "Трекеры", будет хоть что угодно там? Я лично в вашем торренте не нашел. Другие же торренты вы скачиваете наверно с популярных торрент трекеров, где в этом разделе они прописывают свой сервер и по этому серверу идет первоначальный поиск пиров (тех, кто раздает). Информация торрента (название, вес и др) зашита в сам файл `.torrent`, тут нет нечего сверхъестественного. Я вам уже первым комментарием сказал, что в P2P сетях есть технологии поиска пиров в обход трекера, одна из них DHT, которую вы не включили.

Comment: По поводу "Как создать" - вам нужны сервера, те, кто оповестит всех качающих о том, что есть тот самый качающий и раздающий (трекеры). Можете поискать в сети анонимные, вроде был список, но они однодневки по большей части и 90% из них не работают. При создание файла у вас должно быть окно, где они вписываются. Можете поднять и свой сервер, но вам нужен как минимум компьютер работающий 24/7 и имеющий "белый" IP для доступа к нему.

Comment: Я бы с радостью хотел сделать всё это через DHT, но повторюсь, библиотека изменилась и не содержит в себе того же DhtListener, некоторых функций не хватает, либо же они были перенесены, вообщем пока что нет рабочих примеров на форумах и репозиториях.

Comment: У меня есть VDS = компьютер работающий 24/7 с белым IP для доступа к нему. (Windows Server 2016 на нем)

Comment: Я вам выше дал полноценный пример, обновленный пару месяцев назад, не уж то мало? ПОЛНЫЙ торрент клиент на нужной вам библиотеке с поддержкой всего необходимого, берите, копируйте и используйте. Вы прям уперто это не хотите замечать и не хотите искать информацию. Даже тот пример 12 года спокойно можно адаптировать, поняв только логику, а логика там проста - класс, который слушает со своим портом, его вешаете клиенту, запускаете, все.

Comment: Ладно. Я завтра всё более внимательно гляну и адаптирую. Всё же, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Посмотрел, даже не удивился. Нет Top10Listener класса, не в Nuget не на github, пробовал брать Monotorrent папку с github и подключать в проект, в итоге компилируется с ошибками, также не имеет некоторых классов которые даны в примере.

Comment: Потому что вы опять не хотите думать, во первых зачем вам этот топ 10 это все навсего сбор некой статистики. Во вторых, не уж то не догадались перейти на раздел [выше](https://github.com/alanmcgovern/monotorrent/tree/master/src/SampleClient), ведь не похоже это на класс библиотеки, это явный "самопал" для примера, не более.